# How does truly big data import into HDFS before the data scientists grow old and die?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I'm brand-spanking-new to Hadoop and *believe* I'm beginning to see how much different data analytics ("offline") is from the super-low-latency world of web apps. One major thing I'm still struggling to understand is how truly "big data" makes it onto HDFS in the first place.

Say I have 500TB of data stored across a variety of systems (RDBMS, NoSQL, log data, whatever). My *understanding* is that, if I want to write MR jobs to query and analyze this data, I need to first import/ingest it all into HDFS.

But even if I had, say a 1Gbps network connection between each disparate system and my Hadoop cluster, this is 500TB = 500 * 1000Gb = 500,000 GB of data, which at 1Gbps, is 500,000 seconds or **~138** hours to port all the data onto my HDFS cluster. That's almost a week.

And, if my understanding of big data is correct, the terrabyte scale is actually pretty low-key, with many big data systems scaling into the petabyte range. Now we'd be up to months, maybe even *years*, just to be able to run MR jobs against them. If we have systems that are orders of magnitude beyond petabytes, then we're looking at having "flying rocket scooters" buzzing around everywhere before the data is even ready to be queried.

Am I missing something fundamental here? This just doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Normally you put it into the system as you go, and not wait until you have terabytes of data to import. (Assuming you want it all in HDFS and don't get the data directly through various means.)

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton (+1) - that makes sense. So are you saying that, typically (but not necessarily), concurrent writes are made: (a) one write to the main data store (again, NoSQL, log data, whatever) and (b) another concurrent write directly to HDFS? Are tools like Sqoop or Oozie used for this very purpose (concurrent writing/ingestion)?

Comment: Totally depends. For example, you might write  your normalized data into an RDBMS then write some denormalized data into HBase.

Comment: (+1 again) Sure, but then taking your example, you'd start piling up terabytes of data in HBase, which means you're still at the root of the problem: how do you now get the data directly on to HDFS for query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically data is loaded as it's being generated.  However, there are a few tools out there to help with the loading to HDFS.

Apache Flume - https://flume.apache.org/ - Designed for aggregating large amounts of log data.  Flume has many bundled 'sources' which can be used to consume the log data including reading from files, directories, queuing systems, or even accepting incoming data from TCP/UDP/HTTP.  With that you can setup Flume on a number of hosts to parallelize the data aggregation.

Apache Sqoop - http://sqoop.apache.org/ - Designed for bulk loading from structured datastores such as relational databases.  Sqoop uses connectors to connect, structure, and load data to HDFS.  The built in one can connect to any thing that adheres to JDBC 4 specifications.

500TB of data is a lot of data to load, but if it's spread out across multiple systems and formats using Sqoop and/or Flume should make relatively quick work.